# Custom Content Slider stop duplicate

Tags: wp-query

I have been working on this now for little while, I have four post displaying in the carousel, this is fine. when you click the next slide in the carousel the same four posts are displaying

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Thanks

```
        <div id="blog" class="carousel slide carousel-sync" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

        <div class="carousel-inner blog">

        <?php $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1,)); while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="item" id="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" >

       <div class="col-md-6 nopadding view view-ninth" style="padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px;">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
                        <div class="content">
                                                <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
                        <p><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,15) . '...'; ?></p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                                                </div>
                        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" >            
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding view view-ninth" style="padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px;">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
                        <div class="content">
                                                <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
                        <p><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,15) . '...'; ?></p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                                                </div>
                        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item" id="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" >                  
        <div class="col-md-6 nopadding view view-ninth" style="padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px;">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
                        <div class="content">
                                                <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
                        <p><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,15) . '...'; ?></p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                                                </div>
                        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" >            
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding view view-ninth" style="padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px;">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
                        <div class="content">
                                                <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
                        <p><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,15) . '...'; ?></p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                                                </div>
                        </div>                                        


        </div><!-- end item -->        
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


        </div>


</div>                         


                  <a class="carousel-control right " href="#blog" data-slide="next" >R</a>

      <a class="carousel-control left " href="#blog" data-slide="prev" >L</a>                          


                                </div> 
    <?php get_sidebar(  ); // right ?>
                        </div>
<script>

                        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                        $("#blog").find('.item:nth-child(4n-7)').addClass('active');

                                $('.customslider').each(function(){

                                $(this).find('.item:nth-child(4n-7)').addClass('active');

                                })
                        })


</script>
```

Comment: What role does `query_post()` serve there if you loop with query object? Also it (`query_posts()`) shouldn't be used in general.

Comment: Please don't use the wordpress.org tag

Comment: I have been trying different things to fix this issue. forgot to remove it.

Comment: @PieterGoosen sorry

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you are currently using. It is confusing

Comment: @PieterGoosen have now edited it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing all the items in the item class and adding a little

```
<?php $i=1; while ($i <= 1) { ?>
<div class="col-md-6 nopadding view view-ninth" style="padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px;">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
                    <div class="content">
                    <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
                    <p><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,15) . '...'; ?></p>
                    <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>   <?php $i++;}?>
```